# Cron job execute php file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cron

I set my cronjob to run a php file every one minute. The php file access to the database to update a value in a row. Here is the php code

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
mysql_query("UPDATE tanlename SET status = 2 WHERE created < (NOW() - 
INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want the code to set the status of a post to 2 after 1 minute of the its posting time.

Comment: tanlename - Typo ? tablename?

Comment: Thats just example, the data i put in this code here is not accurate

Comment: `mysql_query` change to `mysqli_query` and dont forget parameter 1 set to `$conn`

Comment: @RendiWahyudiMuliawan Could you please explain what do you mean by "don't forget parameter 1 set to $conn"

Comment: You must read here [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `else` here:

You need to change `mysql_` to `mysqli_` - not only is `mysql_` deprecated but also because you're already using `mysqli_` in `$conn`.

Then you need to specify the connection in the `mysqli_query`.

Update your old code from:

```
else {
mysql_query("UPDATE tanlename SET status = 2 WHERE created < (NOW() - 
INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
}
```

to this:

```
else {
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tanlename SET status = 2 WHERE created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
}
```